# Is it possible to use isdigit, isalpha functions with inputed string array?

Tags: c++

i want to check is my array value are number, letter or sign. I want to use this with isdigit or isalpha function. Or hex values, question is how can I can use it with string type input? Or it is impossible?

```
int main()
{
    string sym;
    cout <<"Enter symbols: ";
    getline(cin, sym);
    for(int row = 0; row < sym.size(); row++) 
    {
        cout << sym[row] << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You see I need to print every symbol line with elements type. e.g. `5 - number` , Idk why I am getting that every thing  I write is char type. Maybe you know why?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check array value by using isdigit() and isalpha() functions in C++. You have to include     "ctype.h" library in your code and also include the following statements inside the    "for loop" for performing the required operation in your code:

```
if(isdigit(sym[row])
  cout<<sym[row]<<" is a digit"<<endl;
else if(isalpha[row])
  cout<<sym[row]<<" is an alphabet"<<endl;
else
  cout<<sym[row]<<" is a special character"<<endl;
```

By executing the above code, you will be able to individually check each element of the string(array of characters) and findout whether it is a digit, an alphabet or a special character.

Comment: Note you can stick to the standard C++ library by [including <cctype>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) and use `std::isdigit` etc.

Comment: Yes!! It can even be done using standard c++. I just gave this code as it is easily understandable.